# Pandas Multiindex dataframe.loc results in multitask or normal dataframe depending on level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm working with pandas, have a hierachical multiindex dataframe and use the method .loc to select different parts. Suppose my dataframe consists in the first level of the different patientnames and in the second level of the different bone names. There exists also a third level that has only one value ("triangleQuality") in this example. For each combination I then have an array with values.

So the dataframe looks like the following
[multiindex dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJmiL.png)

To select all bones for one patient I use the command `dataframe.loc[(patient_name, slice(None), "triangleQuality")]`
This results in a new dataframe with multiindex.

If I instead want all patients for one bone I use the command `dataframe.loc[(slice(None), bone_name, "triangleQuality")]` This results in a dataframe with normal index.

So my questions are the following:

1. Why do the results of both commands differ?
2. How do I get a normal (no multiindex) dataframe for the first task (all bones and their values for one patient)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do the results of both commands differ?

What you are currently doing is called '[Accessing Data in a MultiIndex DataFrame in Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-data-in-a-multiindex-dataframe-in-pandas-569e8767201d)'
The way you are accessing the same dataframe is different in itself. In the first command, you are only displaying all bones and their values for one patient. In the second command you are only displaying all patients and their values for one bone

If you want to still keep the not displayed part, you can use brackets and the commands would look like this:

dataframe.loc[(`[patient_name]`, slice(None), "triangleQuality")]
dataframe.loc[(slice(None), `[bone_name]`, "triangleQuality")]

2. How do I get a normal (no multiindex) dataframe for the first task (all bones and their values for one patient)?

`df.loc[('Pat.Nr. 100 NiFr right', slice(None),"triangleQuality")]`

When I run this command I am already getting a single-index dataframe of all bones and their values for one patient